# Creating a virtualenv using Python 3 error

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, virtual, environment, conemu

I have python in ConEMu loaded and am trying to creating a virtual environment to work in.

I used

```
   pip3 install virtualenv --user
```

and it said that virtualenv was usccessfully installed, however then I try to

```
    virtualenv .venv
```

and i get the error message

```
     bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

wondering if anyone else has run into this problem

Answer (score 1):

virtualenv is built into python 3, and called [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). You don't need to install anything with pip.

You can make a virtualenv in python 3 like this:

```
python3 -m venv ve
```